# Remove close button when views are minimised

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I've noticed that views that aren't closeable can still be closed using other methods.

I have some views that are not `closeable` that I've also tagged as `NoDetach`.

I can click to minimise the view, right click it, and close the view. This means I've now closed views that the user shouldn't be able to.

[image: View Properties]

[image: Minimised close menu item]

There are two methods I can see that would fix this:

1. Add an option so the user can add the views back on. This would work but the views should never be able to be closed in the first place.
2. Remove the close menu item

How might I go about removing the menu item?

Comment: That looks like the menu created by `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.TrimStack` in the MinMax addon. I don't see an obvious way to suppress the close entry (other than not using the addon at all).

Comment: That's a problem as we would like to use the addon too. Would it be possible for me to somehow override the TrimStack and use my own custom version?

Comment: I don't know enough about the internals of that addon to say (my RCPs don't use it). Looking at it briefly it doesn't look like it is designed to be overridden.